# Need to implement socket transmission in Android

Tags: android, sockets, implementation

I need to transfer data(generally text) between two android devices using socket implementation, i.e, the device have to receive the data & also send the data to the other device. Can anyone suggest me some regarding this & also please tell me that, is there any examples regarding this Socket Transmission in Android.

Comment: Bluetooth transmission example on android developers might help you to quick start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) is an example demonstrating socket communication between two Android devices.